# Perl touch -t file error for a future date

Tags: date, unix, touch, unix-timestamp

I am trying to touch a file(for referencing date) with a future date something like -
Current date - $date
Fri Jan  6 03:59:55 EST 2017

```
touch -t 201702032359.59 /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
```

on checking the timestamp of the file as -

```
$ ls -lrt /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
```

getting an output with only date and not the entire timestamp(hhmm.sec)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcproc abc 0 Feb  3  2017 /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
```

But for a date with is less than or equal to current it gives correct result -

```
touch -t 201612010000.00 /var/tmp/ME_FILE_START
ls -lrt /var/tmp/ME_FILE_START
-rw-r--r-- 1 abcproc abc 0 Dec  1 00:00 /var/tmp/ME_FILE_START
```

Can someone please suggest why this discrepancy ?

Comment: How is Perl involved?

Comment: Nowhere I think. It's just a plain unix question.

Comment: Try touching a file from >6months ago. You'll see this problem too. `ls` formats date to something that's conveniently human readable. Which is yet another reason why you shouldn't parse `ls` output.

Answer (score 1):

It's just the way ls displays the date. When far from now, the modification time is not displayed.

If you want details regarding the last access / modification / change time, you should be using stat.

```
stat /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
```

You will see the expected output.

For example:

```
[10:29:41]dabi@gaia:~$ touch -t 201702032359.59 /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
[10:29:43]dabi@gaia:~$ ls -ltr /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dabi dabi 0 feb.  3  2017 /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
[10:29:47]dabi@gaia:~$ stat /var/tmp/ME_FILE_END
  File : '/var/tmp/ME_FILE_END'
   Size : 0           Blocks : 0          I/O blocks : 4096   empty file
Device : 803h/2051d       Inode : 5374373     Links : 1
Access : (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  UID : ( 1000/    dabi)   GID : ( 1000/    dabi)
Access : 2017-02-03 23:59:59.000000000 +0100
Change : 2017-02-03 23:59:59.000000000 +0100
Change : 2017-01-06 10:29:43.364630503 +0100
  Birth : -
```

Comment: Which is another reason why you shouldn't parse `ls` output :).